# Returning value of highlighted divs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a "bar" that is highlight-able and will return a value which contains the number of div boxes that were highlighted. For example, when I highlight 5 divs, it should return 5. When I continue on, and highlight another 6 boxes, it should return 6. All of the highlighted results should be in an array `var x = ["5", "6",...];`

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aepxqztL/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $range = $('.range-bar').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    var flag = $(this).hasClass('highlight')
    $range.on('mouseenter.highlight', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight', flag);
    });
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('.range-bar').off('mouseenter')
  })
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about a progress bar?

Comment: I don't think progress bar would fit considering the situation.

Comment: You need to clarify the use-case. For eg. what is the differentiation between the first five highlighted DIVs and the next six? Are you clicking/dragging to highlight items? Is it just a bunch of clicks for the first set and then you hit a 'next' button for the next set?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, are you looking more for something that just returns sets of adjacent black DIVs?

Comment: I've made some changes to the fiddle to reinforce my comment https://jsfiddle.net/0vftp5ja/. These divs represent hours in a 24 hour format with each box representing half an hour. The difference between the highlighted divs are the number of hours and the time. E.g five divs from 0.5 to 1.5 means it starts from 12.30am to 1.30 am and has a duration of one hour.

Comment: So what is the context of the data you want to extract? Does it show you intervals of hours? or something else?

Comment: @thePav I want to extract the value of first and last div highlighted. From the example I gave earlier, it would be 0.5 and 1.5.

Comment: I've added an answer below, let me know if this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery.each to calculate the highlighted divs upon mousedown event

```
function calculateArray(){
  var x = [];
  $("div.range-bar").each(function( index, value ) {
    if($(this).hasClass("highlight"))
      x.push(index);
  });
  return x;
}

var x = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $range = $('.range-bar').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    var flag = $(this).hasClass('highlight')
    $range.on('mouseenter.highlight', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight', flag);
    });
    x = calculateArray();
    console.log(x);    
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $('.range-bar').off('mouseenter')
  })
});
```

See working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/aepxqztL/7/

Comment: Did you see the working demo? You could see the output of the x array in console.

Comment: Sorry for that careless comment. It does work and quite close to what I'm looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello sir. When I highlight the divs it only records the starting point. How do I get to record the ending points as well the moment I stopped dragging?. I can get the ending point but its just that I need to trigger a click to get the new set of array.

Comment: Hi Justin, you could move the two lines of mousedown event  `x = calculateArray();  console.log(x);` to the mouseup event instead to trigger it on the moment you stopped dragging.

Comment: Thank you so much. This perfectly suits what I need. Really happy, thanks again Shadi.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set 2 global vars (a range counter `rangeVal` and a data array `dataSet`) and then increment the `rangeVal` on `mousedown` on each box and then add it to the `dataSet` on `mouseup` and then reset `rangeVal`.

Eg.

```
var dataSet = []; //data array
var rangeVal = 1; //range counter

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $range = $('.range-bar').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    var flag = $(this).hasClass('highlight')
    $range.on('mouseenter.highlight', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('highlight', flag);
      rangeVal++; //Increment on mousedown mouseenter in box
    });
  });

  $('.range-bar').mouseup(function() {
    $('.range-bar').off('mouseenter')
    dataSet.push(rangeVal); //add range counter to data array
    rangeVal = 1; //reset range counter
    $('.results p').text(dataSet.join()); //display data array in results div
  })
});
```

See this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/0vftp5ja/1/

The question is still a little vague but I think this is what you're looking for.

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/0vftp5ja/2/
Modified so that it saves the Start and End value as well as the Range value.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm looking for. thank you so much. But do you think I can also retrieve the starting value and the ending value of the range? Means if I highlight from 0.5 to 2.5, I would be able to retrieve 0.5 and 2.5 in separate arrays. Additionally, when I no longer highlight the divs I want it to be removed in the array.

Comment: @JustinLiwag Checkout this fiddle, I've modified it so that it saves the start, end and range as an object in an array. https://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/0vftp5ja/2/